# Remember user purchase info in server model of in-app purchase

Tags: iphone

IN BUILT_IN MODEL
If i purchase feature through Non-consumable for on application,if i delete it,
If i purchase it again,will apple remember my user_id to purchase it as free?
IN SERVER MODEL?
suppose the app uses server model, may the server use apple to remember that user?
any help please?with explaination?

Comment: please ask a direct and understandable question!

Answer (score 0):

If your user purchases an item and then loads your app onto another device and purchases the same item, it will not charge the user for the purchase. The answers to your questions are in the docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

In particular, on the chapter on making a purchase the docs say:

> If the user attempts to purchase a
>   nonconsumable item they have already
>   purchased, your application receives a
>   regular transaction for that item, not
>   a restore transaction. However, the
>   user is not charged again for that
>   product. Your application should treat
>   these transactions identically to
>   those of the original transaction.